# Python/Sqlite3 : Exception has occurred: sqlite3.OperationalError

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to create a function that will handle API error messages but I get this error message in Python:

```
Exception has occurred: sqlite3.OperationalError
near "Test4": syntax error
```

The server response is:

```
{"message":"Failed to validate one or more request parameters","validationErrors":["Budget name must be unique. 'Test4 - X4574747-PHONE' already exits"]}
```

And my code is:

```
def error():
    if "message" in r.json():
        logText = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime()) + " : " + r.json()['message']
        c.execute("INSERT INTO log VALUES ('"+ logText +"')")
        conn.commit()
        if "validationErrors" in r.json():
            logText = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime()) + " : " + r.json()['validationErrors'][0]
            c.execute("INSERT INTO log VALUES ('"+ logText +"')")
            conn.commit()
        os._exit(1)
```

I can't put my finger on what causes this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your `logText` value in case of `validationErrors`. I guess there is a problem with quotes. Btw best way to insert str into str with quotes is using `%r`. Like `sql = "insert into log values(%r)" % logText`.

Comment: @sashaaero No, the best way is to use parameterized queries: `c.execute("INSERT INTO log VALUES (?)", [logText])`

Comment: In sql yes, but I'm talking about strings generally. But we are working with sql here, so you are right.

Comment: The logText value is : 2018-12-10 23:31:26 : Budget name must be unique. 'Test4 - X4574747-PHONE' already exits

Comment: Yes, you are closing `'` quote before `Test4`. Use the way Dan D. showed.

Comment: Your SQL is `"INSERT INTO log VALUES ('2018-12-10 23:31:26 : Budget name must be unique. 'Test4 - X4574747-PHONE' already exits')"` And it's incorrect.

Comment: I see. Thank you, guys. Dan's code works, but I don't understand it. Sorry, I'm a noob to Python. Any documentation would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logText = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime()) + " : " + r.json()['validationErrors'][0]
c.execute("INSERT INTO log VALUES ('"+ logText +"')")
```

You are sending this SQL `INSERT INTO log VALUES ('2018-12-10 23:31:26 : Budget name must be unique. 'Test4 - X4574747-PHONE' already exits')` and as you see you close `'` quote before `Test4` and that's why SQL doesn't understand what's going on after closing quote.

Use `c.execute("INSERT INTO log VALUES (?)", [logText])`

> Dan's code works, but I don't understand it.

`?` means pass argument from given arguments list. Which is `[logText]`. It is better to use this way to avoid SQL injections.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and link. And  thanks to Dan too for the input